# Exporting boundaries from Google Map Maker

Tags: export, google-maps

If it is possible to export a marked boundaries from Google Map Maker, then how do I do this?

Comment: You can download Google data from Google Map Maker. Terms and Conditions apply. https://services.google.com/fb/forms/mapmakerdatadownload/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it not possible to export anything from google maps.